# Поиск файла на компьютере

Tags: java, файлы, поиск

Изучая работу класса `File`, стало интересно, есть ли у класса `File` какой-то метод для поиска файла на компьютере, если известно только имя файла и расширение?

Comment: Ну что? Разобрались?

Comment: @AntonSorokin Да, спасибо большое, ваш пример с сайта pastebin - единственный, в котором смог разобраться)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375729/search-for-file-in-directory-with-multiple-directories):

```
    private static File findFile(File dir, String name) {
  File result = null; // no need to store result as String, you're returning File anyway
  File[] dirlist  = dir.listFiles();

  for(int i = 0; i < dirlist.length; i++) { 
    if(dirlist[i].isDirectory()) {
      result = findFile(dirlist[i], name);
      if (result!=null) break; // recursive call found the file; terminate the loop
    } else if(dirlist[i].getName().matches(name)) {
      return dirlist[i]; // found the file; return it
    }
  }
  return result; // will return null if we didn't find anything
}
```

Используя  API файлов Java 8:

```
public static File searchFileJava8(final String rootFolder, final String fileName) {
File target = null;
Path root = Paths.get(rootFolder);
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(root, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attr) ->
        path.getFileName().toString().equals(fileName))) {
    Optional<Path> path = stream.findFirst();
    if(path.isPresent()) {
        target = path.get().toFile();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
}
return target;
}
```

Либо, поиск глубиной(самое быстрое решение):

```
public static File searchFileByDeepness(final String directoryName, final String fileName) {
File target = null;
if(directoryName != null && fileName != null) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    if(directory.isDirectory()) {
        File file = new File(directoryName, fileName);
        if(file.isFile()) {
            target = file;
        }
        else {
            List<File> subDirectories = getSubDirectories(directory);
            do {
                List<File> subSubDirectories = new ArrayList<File>();
                for(File subDirectory : subDirectories) {
                    File fileInSubDirectory = new File(subDirectory, fileName);
                    if(fileInSubDirectory.isFile()) {
                        return fileInSubDirectory;
                    }
                    subSubDirectories.addAll(getSubDirectories(subDirectory));
                }
                subDirectories = subSubDirectories;
            } while(subDirectories != null && ! subDirectories.isEmpty());
        }
    }
}


  return target;
}

private static List<File> getSubDirectories(final File directory) {
    File[] subDirectories = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(final File current, final String name) {
            return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
        }
    });
    return Arrays.asList(subDirectories);
}
```

[С сайта pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7Y3G9GmB):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    File f;
    String path, file;
    boolean result = false;
    System.out.println("Enter the required path for search: ");
    path = input.nextLine();
    f = new File(path+".");
    System.out.println("Enter the name of required file: ");
    file = input.nextLine();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
        if(files[i].toString().equals(path+".\\"+file) && files[i].isFile()){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    if(result == true)
        System.out.println("File located in the folder");
    else System.out.println("File was not found ");
```

Выбирайте то, что вам более удобно.

Answer (score 3):

Просмотреть все файлы в директории можно с помощью [`File::listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--). Далее этот метод можно поместить в рекурсивную функцию, которая будет обходить дерево каталогов и проверять наличие файла.

Вот пример:

```
void search(File file) {    
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
       System.out.println("Поиск каталога ... " + file.getAbsoluteFile());

       // у вас есть разрешение на чтение этого каталога?   
       if (file.canRead()) {
          for (File temp : file.listFiles()) {
            if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                search(temp);
            } else {
                if (getFileNameToSearch().equals(temp.getName().toLowerCase())) {           
                    result.add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                }    
            }
          }    
       } else {
         System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "Доступ запрещен");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C сайта [Cyberforum](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread1116248.html):

```
static void func(String path, String find) {
    File f = new File(path);
    //список файлов в текущей папке
    String[] list = f.list();
    //проверка на совпадение
    for (String file : list) {
        if (find.equals(file)) {
            flag=true;
            System.out.println(path + "\\" + file + " ");
            //если найден, то выход
            return;
        }
        if (!path.endsWith("\\")) {
            path += "\\";
        }
        File tempfile = new File(path + file);
        System.out.println(path + file);
        if (!file.equals(".") && !file.equals("..")) { // !!!
            //иначе проверяем, если это папка
            if (tempfile.isDirectory()) {
                //path += file;
                //то рекурсивный вызов этой функции
                func(path + file, find);
                if(flag) return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```